# Calculating travel distance for car with turning radius

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm trying to calculate the travel distance for a car that has a turning radius in order to get to a destination.

[Here's a picture of what I'm trying to figure out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bACq7.png)

The information I know is this:

1. Turning radius of the car(R) - Green lines
2. Distance to the destination(D) - Black line
3. Angle to the destination(Theta) - Angle between the black line to the destination and the blue line that is the heading of the car

I also know that the destination is not inside the turning circle of the car.

What I'm trying to find the lengths of A(yellow line) and B(purple arc).  I'm just not sure how to calculate them from the information I have.  Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Must the car always make a left-hand turn? For some values of $\theta$, the shortest path will involve turning to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the figure below the car is at the origin heading down.

[image]

Point $j$ is the destination and has coordinates $(x_j, y_j)$. From the triangle $Ojk$ it should be easy to see that $$x_j = D*cos(\theta-\frac{\pi}{2})$$

$$y_j = D*sin(\theta-\frac{\pi}{2})$$

To find the distance $A$ we first find the distance $X$. From triangle $cjk$ we find $$X^2=(x_j-R)^2 + y_j^2$$

From triangle $cji$ we similarly find that $$X^2=A^2+R^2$$

Putting these two together we find $$A=\sqrt{(x_j-R)^2 + y_j^2-R^2}$$

That was $A$, now to find the distance B travelled on the circle. This means finding angle $\alpha3$. But $$\alpha3= \pi - (\alpha1 - \alpha2)$$

where $\alpha1$ is the angle $\angle icj$. These angles are easily found as $$\alpha1=arctan(\frac{A}{R})$$

$$\alpha2=arctan(\frac{y_j}{x_j-R})$$

The distance travelled on the circle is thus $$B=R(\pi-arctan(\frac{A}{R})+arctan(\frac{y_j}{x_j-R}))$$

Comment: MathJax hints: 1) if you put a backslash in front of common functions they come out in the right font and spacing, so \sin x gives $\sin x$ instead of sin x giving $sin x$. 2) if you use \left( and \right) for parentheses, they grow to the size of what is inside, so \left( \frac AR \right) gives $\left( \frac AR \right)$

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks. I still have a lot to learn about the subtleties of MathJax.

Comment: It comes with time. You can right click on any MathJax and choose Show Math As -> TeX Commands to see how it was done.

Comment: Great answer and explanation.  Thanks!

Comment: Also for anyone who has the same problem to solve, when the destination isn't behind the car the value of a3 switches to a3 = pi - (a1 + a2)

Comment: You're welcome!